# Routing asio soundcard output to a PC input device

Tags: audio-interfaces, input, asio, signal-routing

I'm using an asio sound card with Ableton live, and would like to route audio input through Ableton and then into another application such as Discord or OBS.

I know there's a non-asio solution to do this using vb-audio virtual cables, but this adds over 100ms of input latency, making it nearly impossible to monitor myself and speak well at the same time.

Are there any solutions that allow me to take advantage of asio input/output processing? If there are no software solutions, are there any hardware solutions?

Comment: Maybe have a look if something like [Voicemeeter Banana](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) can handle it - but Windows' audio routing is a nightmare, without trying to include ASIO & non-ASIO. I'd say 'buy a Mac', but that may be frowned on ;)

Comment: I use a mac professionally (for non-audio stuff), so I have nothing against them, but my home workstation is a beefy Windows desktop that I use for all sorts of media and gaming, so I couldn't really justify it for doing hobby type stuff.

Comment: tbh, I haven't used Windows for audio work in 10 years, though I have a few machine that do domestic 'multimedia' tasks, for which they're reasonably suited. I'd be tempted to start with "why do you need Ableton & could you work without it?" to keep the routing simpler, though I'm guessing the answer is going to involve "VST plugins" which on Windows are not directly accessible by the system :/

Comment: Becides Jack recommended in the only answer (good solution indeed) occasionally this can be done via card's own ASIO routing app, e.g. kX project had such feature.

Comment: I try to do the same thing with OBS. After test several software solution, i finally bought a second external sound card.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Jack](http://jackaudio.org/faq/jack_on_windows.html). I am not sure about the performance in Windows, but it should be at least as fast as asio.